# How can i solve the following error in karma with angular

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I have executed the following line

```
expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith("dateApply");
```

but i got the following **error**:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
>   (evaluating'c.$broadcast("$locationChangeStart",b,a,k.$$state,f).defaultPrevented')

Please help me solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

first defined the `rootScope` at the top.

then inject it in `beforeEach` like this

```
inject(function($injector) {
  rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
});
```

Then in your test case

```
expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith("dateApply");
```

If you are doing minification, make sure rootScope isn't being renamed.

Comment: I have tried the above code but still got error " Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.";

Comment: you need to put a spy on `rootScope.$broadcast` before you can use `toHaveBeenCalledWith` Read the `spyOn` docs.

Comment: ok..but now i tried like this but this one also getting error
spyOn(rootScope,'$broadcast').andCallThrough();